# JsonResult - how to return an empty JSON result?

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ajax call that makes a GET request to one of my controllers action methods.

The ajax call is supposed to get a JSON response and use that to populate a datagrid. The callback function is supposed to fire and construct the grid and hide the loading indicator.

```
  $.getJSON('@Url.Action("Data", "PortfolioManager")' + '?gridName=revenueMyBacklogGrid&loginName=@Model.currentUser.Login', 
        function (data) {    
            ConstructrevenueMyBacklogGrid(data);
            $('#revenueMyBacklogLoadingIndicator').hide();
        });
```

The problem is when the object I am converting to a JsonResult object has no data - it's just an empty collection.

> returnJsonResult = Json(portfolioManagerPortalData.salesData.myYTDSalesClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

In this example it is the collection `myYTDSalesClients` that returns empty (which is ok and valid - sometimes there won't be any data).

The JSON object then returns an empty response (blank, nadda) and since it's not valid JSON, the callback function won't fire. Thus the loading indicator still shows and it looks like it's just loading forever.

So, how do I return an empty JSON result `{}` instead of a blank?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
if (portfolioManagerPortalData.salesData.myYTDSalesClients == null) {
    returnJsonResult = Json(new object[] { new object() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
else {
    returnJsonResult = Json(portfolioManagerPortalData.salesData.myYTDSalesClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Hey that's awesome. Unfortunately it's telling me it's not valid. It's returning {}. I guess I need [{}]. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I am an idiot. It was something else entirely. But! I did figure out the [{}] thing if anyone needs it...returnJsonResult = Json(new object[] { new object() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

Answer (score 28):

As of asp.net mvc 5 you could simple write:

```
Json(new EmptyResult(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

Answer (score 7):

In .Net Core 3.0 for a controller of type ControllerBase you can do this:

```
return new JsonResult(new object());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.NET as a default Serializer for serializing JSON instead of default Javascript Serializer:

This will handle the scenario of sending data if its NULL.

For e.g.

Instead of this in your action method:

```
return Json(portfolioManagerPortalData.salesData.myYTDSalesClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
```

You need to write this in your action method:

```
return Json(portfolioManagerPortalData.salesData.myYTDSalesClients, null, null);
```

Note: 2nd and 3rd parameter null in above function is to facilitate overloads of Json method in Controller class.

Also you do not need to check for null in all of your action methods like above:

```
        if (portfolioManagerPortalData.salesData.myYTDSalesClients == null)
        {
            returnJsonResult = Json(new object[] { new object() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            returnJsonResult = Json(portfolioManagerPortalData.salesData.myYTDSalesClients, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Below is the code for JsonNetResult class.

```
public class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
{
    public JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings { get; set; }
    public Formatting Formatting { get; set; }

    public JsonNetResult()
    {
        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.ContentType = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType)
          ? ContentType
          : "application/json";

        if (ContentEncoding != null)
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;

        JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(response.Output) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };

        JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(SerializerSettings);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, Data);

        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Also You need to add below code in BaseController if any in your project:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a NewtonSoft.Json.JsonNetResult object that serializes the specified object to JavaScript Object Notation(JSON).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <param name="contentType"></param>
    /// <param name="contentEncoding"></param>
    /// <returns>The JSON result object that serializes the specified object to JSON format. The result object that is prepared by this method is written to the response by the ASP.NET MVC framework when the object is executed.</returns>
    protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, System.Text.Encoding contentEncoding)
    {
        return new JsonNetResult
        {
            Data = data,
            ContentType = contentType,
            ContentEncoding = contentEncoding
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### Return Empty JSON {} in ASP.NET Core WebAPI

**ASP.NET Core** comes with a large family of Response Types that are housed under their MVC or Web API application model. Most deliver their new `IActionResult` type that controls all the various types of content types, Http Headers, and server Status Codes needed to deliver a complete response to a caller. However, **they are not consistent in what they deliver to end-users when something goes wrong**, data is missing, an exception occurs, or empty data occurs.

Many of Microsoft's *interpretations* of the standard `Http Server Codes` do not return data, while others returns a clump of JSON for certain types of status code errors that include a proprietary set of error codes they recommend. They address the status code, but not the needs of say an empty JSON data set. Sometimes Microsoft exceptions or server status code responses flip to status codes that do not return content by default, or disallow it completely. So the user gets nothing but the status code, in some cases, leaving them with an error when no JSON is returned. Even a few of their 200 series response codes do not allow content to be returned. Some of this is standardized under the HTTP rules. Others are not.

**To fix all these problems in ASP.NET Core**, when something goes wrong, its better to have a consistent plan. It's better to just deliver a standard 200 Ok with a standard JSON error or empty JSON packaged response, or just return your a cherry-picked *error* status code that allows JSON or text content responses, then add your chosen JSON response with what helps your end-user cope with the error: An empty JSON object {}, or a JSON error package, an error string, a redirect to an error page, etc.

One or more of these issues might be why you never got your empty JSON object.

If you prefer to give your end-users a minimal JSON response, you must capture all of Microsoft's errors/statuscode/exception combinations on the server then return a standardized packaged response. I prefer returning the 'application/json' content-type for the browser to recognize the JSON, then add the 200 status code, but return empty JSON {}. You must make sure your empty JSON or JSON error message is formatted correctly.

I recommend you return 200 ok, even for error status codes, so you can control what end-users consuming your data dont get bogged down trying to interpret a dozen eror status codes. To do that set the following:

1. Return the **Http Header Status Code of 200 Ok - Successful**
2. Return the **Http Header Content-type of "application/json"**
3. Return the **empty JSON object as {}**

The good news is ASP.NET Core 7 comes with several "ActionResult" subtypes of Response Objects that do all three steps above for you instantly, though the documentation does not clearly state that:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetJSON(string? text = "")
{
  return new ObjectResult(new{});
}

// Returns: {}
```

`ObjectResult` is a type of `IActionResult` that includes the ability to return any object converted to any content-type, and deliver the Status Code 200 Ok. If it sees an {} it defaults to JSON.

Be sure to test Response you get from every Microsoft ASP.NET Core endpoint using ActionResult types. When they fail, all the ActionResult types like ObjectResult and their family of helper functions return various types of status codes and error results that do not consistently deliver what you expect. But if you focus on a consistent OUTPUT to the end-user and not get bogged down in error status codes, you can keep the errors and exceptions on the server side.